# [Facebook][Bug?] Why is the redirect URI always link to static.facebook.com instead of my own?

Tags: facebook, redirect, oauth

In the setting of my App, I have set the site URL to be `http://localhost/`, in the app domain, I have indicated `localhost`.

Followed by in the Facebook Login Product, I have set Valid OAuth redirect URIs to be http://localhost.

but launch in my application, it gives me `URL Blocked .... redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app's Client OAuth Settings...`

the redirect URI link is `http%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2Fao6eUeuGXQq.js%3Fversion%3D4`

No matter what I change in the OAuth, the URI remains the same.

Anyone able to help?

Comment: Nope. just localhost wont do. U need to put with port too. i.e `http://localhost:3000/`

Comment: @Smit Ohh this totally solved it, thank you very much! you can put as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct one! But just to clarify, why is it that I must add the port in? is it because of the same origin policy issue?

Comment: _“why is it that I must add the port in?”_ – because the port is part of the URL? And with a different port, it would be a different URL?

Comment: @DreamWeaver I have added answer with explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Just localhost wont do. U need to put with port too. i.e http://localhost:3000/

There is NO url called `http://localhost/` and If you put a port, it just talks about specific domain.

For example, if you put `localhost` which considered wild. For example what if you put `www` in your allowed url? It is considered illegal.

If you specify the port i.e `http://localhost:3000/` then u just refereing to one domian at a time. And it is not wild nor illegal. Through this u are just allowing `www.stackoverflow.com`